# Google Authentication Never gets to OnCreatingTicket

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, .net-core, google-authentication

I am trying to get Google authentication working with my .Net Core 2.1 site.  The issue is that after I have selected my google account and allowed my app to access my info I get the following error: [image]
The Code I am using is :

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie()
            .AddGoogle("Google", options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
                options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
                options.Events = new OAuthEvents
                {
                    OnCreatingTicket = context =>
                    {
                        //Never gets to this point
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });
```

The Nuget Package I am using is : Microsoft.AspNetCore.All

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your trying to connect to HTTP all of googles auth servers are on HTTPs.

Comment: Do you have a call to `UseAuthentication` in `Configure`? I believe that middleware is responsible for serving up your `signin-google` endpoint (among many other things).

Comment: @KirkLarkin  Thanks very much,  I had another look and must have added it without realising it.  I had also included a Route("signin-google") to a controller while trying to figure out the issue.  If you add an answer I will mark it as correct.  Thanks very much